# Ubuntu Installation Process Hard Drive!

Tags: drivers, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I have a few question's regarding the Ubuntu Installation Process. I am planning on installing Ubuntu 16.04 since it's a LTS version. Here is the spec.
-I have a AMD processor since 2012 tower.
-64 bit processor
-500 GB of Free Data Individual Hard Drive
-3 to 4 gigabytes of RAM!
-I do not have a graphic's card, but what would you advice!
-Dell

What would you advice for installation and what about the / partition, home partition and a swap partition. I am having the roughest time for this part of the installation since it is the most important part of Ubuntu Linux

Thank You
Ronald D. Marlow III

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

- 30 GB for `/`
- 20 GB for `/swap` (depending really on what you are going to do; for me you have not enough RAM)
- 450 GB for `/home` (or whatever is left, I'm rounding the values so you get the idea)

You can play with the size of `/` depending on the amount of software you are going to install.

For me, the formula boils down to: 30 GB for `/`, 16 GB for `/swap` (I have 16 GB RAM, so `/swap` is rarely used, but I like to have it like that!)...the rest for `/home`.